# Any way to override the swift built in print function including constant variables? (#line, #function etc)

Tags: swift, logging

I want to be able to override the default Swift standard library print function and include the line number and function name. I have tried several methods such as

```
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = \(#line), terminator: String = #function { 
    let output = items.map { "\(terminator) \(separator) -> \($0)" }.joined(separator: " ")
    Swift.print(output, terminator: "\n")
}
```

This correctly prints out the function name of the calling method, however the line number is set to the line number of the print function. I therefore tried changing the separator type to `Int` and passing `#line` to it as its default value.

This results in an "ambiguous use of function" error, and changing the signature doesn't help either as the default implementation is called in preference to my function.

I have looked at extensions and even swizzling but neither of these seem fruitful in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that in my case a signature change does solve the issue. By being specific about the type passed to the `items` argument, my custom method is called.

```
public func print(_ items: String..., filename: String = #file, function : String = #function, line: Int = #line, separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {

    let pretty = "\(URL(fileURLWithPath: filename).lastPathComponent) [#\(line)] \(function)\n\t-> "
    let output = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)
    Swift.print(pretty+output, terminator: terminator)

}
```

Note that all the print statements I care about pass Strings. The default implementation is called otherwise:

```
print(1+1) 
// 2

print("Hello, World!")
// ExampleVC.swift [#101] viewDidLoad()
//    -> Hello, World!

print("Hello", "World", separator: ", ", terminator: "!\n")
// ExampleVC.swift [#101] viewDidLoad()
//    -> Hello, World!
```